# Finding Memory leaks in VS 2013 release build while using Deleaker in the following code. Are they really memory leaks?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-management

I am using [Deleaker](https://www.deleaker.com/) tool to find the memory leaks in my application.

Below are the code snippet files where I am getting the memory leaks.

```
class FileManager
{

    .....
    std::fstream _dfs;
    std::mutex _dmutex;
    Write(const char *l_charbuffer);
    .....

};

void FileManager::Write(const char *l_charbuffer)
{

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_dmutex);
    _dfs << l_charbuffer << endl;
}


class LogManager
{

    .....
    Initialize(const char *l_charbuffer);
    .....

};

LogManager::Initialize()
{

    .....
    std::thread logexcpthread(&LogManager::ExcpThread, this);
    .....
}
```

When I am running my application in the Release build, Deleaker tool has shown memory leaks in the following lines:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_dmutex); // Write method of FileManager

std::thread logexcpthread(&LogManager::ExcpThread, this); // Initialize method of LogManager
```

I am not sure are those really memory leaks or not? If anyone has come across this kind of problem, please help me on this?

Is there a tool limitation in Release build for this kind of code?

Note: But I have not seen these memory leaks in Debug build.

Comment: VS 2013 is an old compiler. Us VS 2017.

Comment: what's LogManager::ExcpThread. code is missing pieces. as it presented now main thing is that your thread you create is a local object with life ending at exit from Initialize, unless you move it somewhere else. something probably creates copy of manager class (and of mutex), that may explain other warning.

Comment: Deleaker's author here. It's a good idea to share call stacks for these false positives. It's highly likely that it's some kind of one-time-initialization - to check it just add additional variable of type `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`. Does it add some leak?